# How to fix constraint layout when height="wrap_content" doesn't works?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

Implementing my educational project that looks like instagram post page.
And faced with problem that `ViewPager` height="wrap_content" doesn't works, so it makes all of the rest blocks go down over the screen area.

Now it looks like

[image]

And should be something like

[image]

Fragment xml that contains `view pager`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PostFragment">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/profilePhoto"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_profile"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/profileName"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profilePhoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/locationText"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profilePhoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/username" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageLike"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profilePhoto" />



<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/midGuideline1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/midGuideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/midGuideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/midGuideline1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageLike"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/like"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/comments"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comments"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageLike"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookmark"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/favorites"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usernameDesc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/profileName"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageLike" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/usernameDesc"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageLike" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/createdAt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/few_days_ago"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Image fragment xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ImageFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/post_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer the question but anyway, the problem might be with the line following constraint on `viewpager` :-

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageLike"
```

Remove the line.

Exactly can not explain why this happens but you should try it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. But thanks, it's never too late)